# ¿Cómo reconocer qué ImageButton se ha pulsado en un GridView de un Fragment en Android?

Tags: java, android, gridview, adapter, onclicklistener

Tengo una Activity con dos fragment dinámicos por el momento. Cuando se pulsa uno de los ImageButtons de la Activity, se carga uno de los fragmentos.
En cada fragment se cargan otros ImageButtons, que al ser pulsados, se carga una palabra en el TextView de la Activity, que varía en función del ImageButton que se haya pulsado.

Esto funciona cuando creo cada ImageButton uno a uno, pero si los creo con un GridView, no funciona porque el id del ImageButton es siempre el mismo.
No consigo encontrar la forma de distinguir cuál es el que se pulsa, para así mostrar la palabra asociada a ese ImageButton concreto.
En cada ImageButton cargo un objeto de tipo Pictogram con la palabra y la uri para que se vea la imagen deseada.

Utilizo un adapter para crear el GridView en el código y una interfaz para comunicar la Activity y los fragments, ahora mismo funciona el método showTextImage, que recibe un View pero con el problema de que no puedo distinguir los botones. He creado otro método onPictogramClick que recibe un int, intentando capturar la posición de los ImageButtons, pero no funciona.
También lo he intentando con RecyclerVIew (holder), onOptionsItemSelected, onItemClick, OnClickListener...

Agradecería algo de ayuda.

> Código del Activity:
>
> > 

```
public class Translator extends AppCompatActivity implements ComunicationFragments {

    // Reference to Cloud Storage
    ...

    // ImageButtons to show the images of the Activity.
    private ImageButton acciones;
    private ImageButton aseo;
    private ImageButton comida;
    private ImageButton salud;
    private ImageButton sensaciones;
    private ImageButton propios;
    private ImageButton quiero;
    private ImageButton imageBtnClick;

    public AccionesFragment accionesFragment = new AccionesFragment();
    public AseoFragment aseoFragment = new AseoFragment();

    public TextView viewTextImage;

    public String imageName = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_translator);

        acciones = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageBtnAcciones);
        aseo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageBtnAseo);
        comida = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageBtnComida);
        salud = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageBtnSalud);
        sensaciones = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageBtnSensaciones);
        propios = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageBtnPropios);
        quiero = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageBtnQuiero);
        //ImageButton of the Grid.
        imageBtnClick = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageBtnPictogramItem);

        //Collect the xml textView:
        viewTextImage = findViewById(R.id.textViewMuestraTexto);

        //ImageButtons of the Activity.
        Glide.with(this)
                .load("url")
                .into(acciones);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load("url")
                .into(aseo);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load("url")
                .into(comida);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load("url")
                .into(salud);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load("url")
                .into(sensaciones);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load("url")
                .into(propios);
    }


    public void showTextImage(View view) {
        final int id1 = R.id.imageBtnQuiero;
        final int id2 = R.id.imageBtnCaminar;
        final int id3 = R.id.imageBtnClick;

        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case id1:
                imageRef = storageRef.child("quiero ");
                imageName += imageRef.getName();
                viewTextImage.setText(imageName);
                break;
            case id2:
                imageRef = storageRef.child("caminar ");
                imageName += imageRef.getName();
                viewTextImage.setText(imageName);
                break;
            case id3:
                imageRef = storageRef.child("uno ");
                imageName += imageRef.getName();
                viewTextImage.setText(imageName);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }*/

    }

    public void deleteTextView(View view) {
        imageName = "";
        viewTextImage.setText(imageName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictogramClick(int position) {

        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                imageRef = storageRef.child("duchar ");
                imageName += imageRef.getName();
                viewTextImage.setText(imageName);
                break;
            case 1:
                imageRef = storageRef.child("aseo ");
                imageName += imageRef.getName();
                viewTextImage.setText(imageName);
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }

    }

    //Change the fragment.
    public void initFragment(View view) {
        //Incluir el contenedor para mostrar los fragmentos.
       ...
    }

}
```

> Código del fragment:
>
> > 

```
public class AseoFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ComunicationFragments cListener;

    // Reference to Cloud Storage
    ...

    GridView gridAseo;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public AseoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static AseoFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        AseoFragment fragment = new AseoFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aseo, container, false);

        gridAseo = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridViewAseo);

        AdapterPictogram adapterPictogram = new AdapterPictogram(getActivity());

        gridAseo.setAdapter(adapterPictogram);

        return view;
    }

    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        if (context instanceof ComunicationFragments) {
            cListener = (ComunicationFragments) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " Must be implement ComunicationFragments");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        cListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.action_settings)
            return true;

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Pictogram item = (Pictogram) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        cListener.showTextImage(view);
    }
}
```

> Código del Adapter:
>
> > 

```
public class AdapterPictogram extends BaseAdapter {
    Context contextAdapter;

    public AdapterPictogram(Context contextAdapter) {
        this.contextAdapter = contextAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Pictogram.ITEMS.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Pictogram getItem(int position) {
        return Pictogram.ITEMS[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return getItem(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    //Will run as many times as items we have in the list
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View view, @NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) contextAdapter.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pictogram_grid_item, viewGroup, false);
        }
        ImageButton imageBtnPictoAdapter = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageBtnPictogramItem);

        final Pictogram itemAdapter = getItem(position);
        Glide.with(contextAdapter)
                .load(itemAdapter.getUrlStorage())
                .into(imageBtnPictoAdapter);

        imageBtnPictoAdapter.setImageURI(itemAdapter.getUrlStorage());

        return view;
   }
```

> Objeto que se muestra en el ImageButton:
>
> > 

```
public class Pictogram {
    private int idPictogram;
    private String pictoName;
    private Uri urlStorage;

    public Pictogram() {
    }

    public Pictogram(int idPictogram, String pictoName, Uri urlStorage) {
        this.idPictogram = idPictogram;
        this.pictoName = pictoName;
        this.urlStorage = urlStorage;
    }

    public int getidPictogram() {
        return idPictogram;
    }

    public String getPictoName() {
        return pictoName;
    }

    public Uri getUrlStorage() {
        return urlStorage;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return pictoName.hashCode();
    }

    public static Pictogram[] ITEMS = {
            new Pictogram(0, "duchar ", Uri.parse("uri")),
            new Pictogram(1, "hacer pis ", Uri.parse("uri"))
    };

    public  static Pictogram getItem(int id) {
        for (Pictogram item : ITEMS){
            if ((item.getId() == id)){
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas identificar los ImageButton o cualquier vista, puedes asignarle una etiqueta al crearlo o cuando inicia tu aplicaciòn usando el mètodo `setTag()`:

```
 findViewById(R.id.imageBtnQuiero).setTag("BotonQuiero");
```

de esta puedes obtener la etiqueta en base a su id

```
String nombre = view.getTag();
```

Comment: Lo he probado, pero no funciona. Creo que es porque al crear el GridView del Fragment, crea todos los ImageButtons con el mismo id (es el ImageButton imageBtnPictoAdapter que tengo en el Adapter), así que estaría asignando las etiquetas al mismo id continuamente.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente lo he resuelto utilizando en el layout un Table Row que, aunque tengo que crear los ImageButtons uno a uno, los ubica y da espacio entre ellos automáticamente, lo que ahorra bastante tiempo.